# How to prevent players form breaking the rules of the game?

Tags: virtual-reality

There is an online virtual simulation that simulates an entire virtual universe  for players to explore. It has over 29 billion human and non-human players on it, and employees of the company that made the game, called Overseers, are charged with making sure that players follow the rules of the game. The Overseers  can administer any punishment the see necessary except removing them from the game( the company wants all players to stay, so they can get money) So, how could the Overseers punish players for breaking rules?

**** ABOUT THE GAME****
The game is accessed by a helmet The is directly connected to the brain. When a player touches, feels, hears, or taste something, the helmet stimulates that part of the brain to make them feel that feeling. The game has thousands of species playing the game, and it simulates the entire Milky Way galaxy in full. The laws of the game are

*No hacking to give yourself an unfair advantage

- No one can threaten another player online, no exceptions
- No one can say speciesist claims on the game

Comment: Needs a lot more detail about how players connect to, play and where they can do this.  Also needs detail on what the law (e.g. civil rights and contract law) allows and prevents them from doing.  As it stands this Q is too broad, IMO.

Comment: I think a less broad question would be "how could they not punish people?"  You just gave these Overseers access to basically the entire sensory experience of an individual.  I don't think I could ever run out of answers to the question of how one might do punishment.  It is literally limitless, and that's not even considering the aspect of how species should be treated differently.

Comment: Also, not included in your question, but "no one can threaten another player online" is a tremendously demanding rule to put in place, subject to dramatic individual interpretation.  For example, Klingons could probably never play the game because their every day casual demenor could be seen as threatening by other species.

Comment: Helmet wired to brain to generate sensations ?  The wet dream of every IT support person who wanted to make the customer on the other end just scream.  So the question is, what stops the Overseers from zapping people and inflicting pain from "ouch" all the way up to "GGNNNNRRRRRRRR !!!!!" through the helmet ?

Answer (score 4):

Back in the day (over twenty years ago now) I ran a MUD (Multi User Dungeon) text based game while at university. I created something called "The Curse of the Gods".

The curse was interesting in so far as players couldn't see the curse, only gods could detect it so players had no way of knowing they were cursed unless a god told them. What the curse did was make them unlucky. The chance of a monster dodging or blocking their attack was doubled and their chance was halved. The chance of a special attack was doubled and the player's chance halved.

Suddenly a normal fight became that bit harder. Players needed to drink more healing potions etc etc etc. The great thing is players didn't know if they were actually unlucky or cursed thus troublemakers were paranoid about upsetting the gods.

The best punishment is when people are not sure they are actually being punished. People will do stuff if they think you're not watching and can get away with it but when they can't see you and can't tell if they've been caught, they will behave much better.

Think of it as artificial karma.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods that real world gaming companies use to stop people from cheating in their online games.

**Reduce the quality of their experience**

Slow down their in-game movement speed, take away their in-game money, anything of the sort that might reduce their fun with the game as punishment for trying to ruin it for others.

**A Server for nothing but Cheaters**

In one of the Marvel vs Capcom games, Capcom had a problem with people leaving the game early. So what did they do? If someone kept leaving games early, they would be put on a server filled with other people who kept leaving early.

Something similar to this would be useful for your simulation. If they're going to cheat the game, then they may as well use it to cheat against other cheaters so that the experience isn't ruined for non-cheaters on the normal servers.

**Obnoxious Labelling**

This is a tactic that Payday 2 uses for cheaters. If someone is cheating in a game, above their head is displayed in huge red lettering the word "CHEATER". If this simulation is important enough, then this will be a huge source of shame and embarrassment for the cheaters, preventing them from wanting to risk it.

**Doing nothing at all**

Ironically, this might be the most effective way of dealing with them. If the Overseers simply watch for people cheating, then they can fix the bugs and hacks that they used to cheat the game.

Once these are patched, then the cheaters won't be able to cheat anymore, but will still keep playing the game. Saving resources of the Overseers for fixing bugs and hacks rather than spending them on punishing players will allow the simulation to be uncheatable, and prevent future cheaters from using the same exploits.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is effectively a simulation of real life; you've got a full Milky Way simulation and full sensation - so I'd start with how you punish cheaters in real life if there was no death penalty, which (ironically) is a pretty good simulation of what you want to do in the game.

So; you have fines, imprisonment, isolation (prison et al), community service, public ridicule, etc.

Fines have already been discussed; just take money off them. Public ridicule has already been discussed and is a reasonable analogue for the Stocks of old. If you don't restrict them from the game, you can always restrict the areas they can visit (similar to the system security levels in EVE Online) and potentially do that to a degree which isolates them to very specific systems.

Community Service? Restrict their combat abilities, give them only access to mining or salvage capabilities (or equivalent); you could also tie this to a credit value - 'You owe us 2 million tonnes of ore from X mine, all directly mined by yourself from this date on before your service has expired and you can access the other functions in the game again'. In other words, you're taking the ore or other materials from them until their debt to 'society' is paid. This effectively is the equivalent of an effort fine rather than a money fine.

How do other species punish their criminals or cheats? What would they find unpleasant. Given that this sounds like one large simulation, knowing how these matters are managed in the real world (galaxy?) might actually help answer this question, and in cases where you don't want to kick people off the server (equivalent of the death sentence) check out how countries that don't have a death penalty handle matters such as pre-meditated murder for inspiration.